# 404 Not Found with ngrok and Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, ngrok

I'm trying to debug a bot locally on Bot Framework Emulator.

I've installed ngrok and I made it start with the emulator itself (using the settings provided by the framefork).
The bot starts correctly using `npm start`, so I've putted the URL on Bot Framework Emulator and I checked the debug mode.

As it starts the emulation stops [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S2CM.jpg) and looking at the ngrok traffic inspector I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89lMY.jpg).

I've already tried to restart the framework, the bot itself and check if ngrok was already running (I couldn't find any clue about this), so any advice would be useful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I used to create a teams conversation bot in c#, and when I test it in local environment, I need to use ngrok to expose my service to the internet so that the bot service I created in azure portal can listen.

I used this command `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite 3978`, then I can get a 'https' url that is the same as localhost:3978 and set this url+'/api/messages' as 'Messaging endpoint'.

By the way, I need to set appId and app secret in appSetting.json with the value of my azure ad application created when creating 'bot channel registration'. I remembered that if I used error appId, ngrok will get 404 error.

=====================UPDATE=========================

As I really can't understand the error, pls compared your actions with mine and provide more details if needed.

I installed Bot Framework Emulator and test it locally. First I [installed it](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/tag/v4.11.0), and I followed the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) to make the configuration. I used c# as I metioned above, so when my bot program running locally, it will show me the successful website with a url like 'http://localhost:3978/', so I open a bot in emulator like below, then click 'Connect', pls note here, I never did any other configurations such as set environment variable, all actions are included in the screenshot:

[image]

After these steps, I can reach it. By the way, if I didn't enter appid and secret, I will get an error 'Unauthorized', if I used wrong id and secret, an 'incorrect' error will appear.
[image]

You are using nodejs to compose a bot, so maybe the appId and secret can be found in .env?
[image]

Comment: I've tried this command, but Bot Framework Emulator doesn't seem to see that ngrok is running. I've met two problems: 1. If I use this command, it will give me an error like "Failed to spawn ngrok" while starting my emulation; 2. I've tried again by making ngrok start with the emulation, but it simply stops, I can't even get the welcome phrase of my bot.

Comment: UPDATE: I can't edit the previous commnt so... I want to add that the error "Failed to spawn ngrok" is happening even when I use your command and I don't start ngrok with the emulator, it happened right now.

Comment: @SimonaPentangelo Did your problem solved? Any progress?

Comment: @SimonaPentangelo, is your issue resolved?

Comment: @Tiny-wa I'd like to tag also @ranusharao but it doesn't seem to work. Anyway after some days I managed to resolve the issue, I didn't use the command ngrok `http -host-header=rewrite 3978` because it didn't work for me, but I cannot tell what in the end made it work.

Comment: @SimonaPentangelo ok, that's fine, good luck :)